# html pages show � (questions marks) instead of japan character in server

Tags: html, unicode, character

```
This works fine in localhost, but not in server and top of the page contain 
<!doctype html>
    <html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       </head>
    </html>
```

page contents not from db. my code look like

```
if ($lan == "english")
   echo "Sign up if you would like to receive occasional treats from us.";
else
   echo "あなたは私たちから時折お菓子を受け取りたい場合は、サインインをしてください。";
```

this japan contents will shows question marks

Comment: And your file itself is also encoded in utf8 ?

Comment: Your server perhaps sends a different header for the file. Try adding `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` at the very beginning of your PHP file.

Comment: Dear Sirko, i add charset in top of my page.

Comment: Konrad its not working.

Comment: Does your browser recognize the correct encoding? Try explicitly setting the text encoding to UTF-8 in your browser (in Safari it's under View -> Text Encoding). If the browser does not recognize the encoding correctly, open the network tab in the developer tools of your browser and check the Content-Type property of the Response-Header.

Comment: my browser is in utf-8, Konrad its works fine in localhost, and not working in server